# Wagtail not using clean method of custom form

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have got a basic page with a custom base_form_class, i want to use the form to add validation to related orderables. It is defined like so

```html
class HomePage(Page):
    ...
   
    base_form_class = HomePageForm
    ...
```

And the form is defined like

```html
class HomePageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        #some added validation
        return cleaned_data
```

But wagtail keeps using the clean method of the WagtailAdminPageForm, no matter what. Has anyone encountered this issue? When i put a breakpoint in the clean method of wagtailadminpageform i can see that the form is in fact an instance of HomePageForm but it just does not use the correct clean method (or possibly, i am using the wrong clean method)